# Php script failing for mysql insert, number of elements in type def. string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've had some assistance in finishing this script which selects from a cloned table on a remote server and inserts the updated records to the identical table on another server. However, when running this in powershell now I get the message: `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement` and `Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`. I get 59 rows of each error for each row it's attempting to insert, so I know there's something wrong with all 59 elements of bind_param, but that's all I know.

I'm familiar with MYSQL but not so much with php and I"ve had nothing but problems with this. I just want a stable way to read the newest records from the remote server and insert them to the new server. I'm using the max `SESSIONID` which is an AI Primary Key to see what rows are new on the remote server.

Please help me to bypass these errors

```
      <?php

      ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

              // Create connection
              $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
              $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

              // Check connection
              if ($conn->connect_error) {
                  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
              }
              echo "Connected successfully";

              // Check connection2
              if ($conn2->connect_error) {
                  die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
              }
              echo "Connected successfully";


            //Start queries

            $latest_result = $conn2->query("SELECT MAX(`SESSIONID`) FROM `ambition`.`session`");
            $latest_row = $latest_result->fetch_row();
            $latest_session_id = $latest_row[0];

            //Select All rows from the source phone database
            $source_data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `cdrdb`.`session` WHERE `SESSIONID` > $latest_session_id");

              // Loop on the results
              while($source = $source_data->fetch_assoc()) {

                  // Check if row exists in destination phone database
                  $row_exists = $conn2->query("SELECT SESSIONID FROM ambition.session WHERE SESSIONID = '".$source['SESSIONID']."' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

                      //if query returns false, rows don't exist with that new ID.
                      if ($row_exists->num_rows == 0){

                            //Insert new rows into ambition.session
                            $stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO ambition.session (SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE,ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING,CREATIONTIMESTAMP,ALERTINGTIMESTAMP,CONNECTTIMESTAMP,DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP,HOLDTIMESECS,LEGTYPE1,LEGTYPE2,INTERNALPARTYTYPE1,INTERNALPARTYTYPE2,SERVICETYPEID1,SERVICETYPEID2,EXTENSIONID1,EXTENSIONID2,LOCATION1,LOCATION2,TRUNKGROUPNAME1,TRUNKGROUPNAME2,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO,ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1,SERVICEEXTENSION1,SERVICEEXTENSION2,SERVICENAME1,SERVICENAME2,MISSEDUSERID2,ISEMERGENCYCALL,NOTABLECALLID,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID,ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,ACCOUNTCODE,ACCOUNTCLIENT,ORIGINATINGLEGID,SYSTEMRESTARTNO,PATTERN,HOLDCOUNT,AUXSESSIONTYPE,DEVICEID1,DEVICEID2,ISLEG1ORIGINATING,ISLEG2ORIGINATING,GLOBALCALLID,CADTEMPLATEID,CADTEMPLATEID2,ts,INITIATOR,ACCOUNTNAME,APPNAME,CALLID,CHRTYPE,CALLERNAME,serviceid1,serviceid2)


                            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") or die(mysqli_error($conn2)) ;


                            $stmt->bind_Param("i,s,s,s,i,i,s,s,s,s,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,s,s,s,s,i,i,i,s,s,s,s,i,i,i,i,s,s,s,i,i,s,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,s,i,s,s,s,i,s,i,i"
                                                 ,$source['SESSIONTYPE']
                                                 ,$source['CALLINGPARTYNO']
                                                 ,$source['FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO']
                                                 ,$source['DIALPLANNAME']
                                                 ,$source['TERMINATIONREASONCODE']
                                                 ,$source['ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING']
                                                 ,$source['CREATIONTIMESTAMP']
                                                 ,$source['ALERTINGTIMESTAMP']
                                                 ,$source['CONNECTTIMESTAMP']
                                                 ,$source['DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP']
                                                 ,$source['HOLDTIMESECS']
                                                 ,$source['LEGTYPE1']
                                                 ,$source['LEGTYPE2']
                                                 ,$source['INTERNALPARTYTYPE1']
                                                 ,$source['INTERNALPARTYTYPE2']
                                                 ,$source['SERVICETYPEID1']
                                                 ,$source['SERVICETYPEID2']
                                                 ,$source['EXTENSIONID1']
                                                 ,$source['EXTENSIONID2']
                                                 ,$source['LOCATION1']
                                                 ,$source['LOCATION2']
                                                 ,$source['TRUNKGROUPNAME1']
                                                 ,$source['TRUNKGROUPNAME2']
                                                 ,$source['SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM']
                                                 ,$source['SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO']
                                                 ,$source['ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1']
                                                 ,$source['SERVICEEXTENSION1']
                                                 ,$source['SERVICEEXTENSION2']
                                                 ,$source['SERVICENAME1']
                                                 ,$source['SERVICENAME2']
                                                 ,$source['MISSEDUSERID2']
                                                 ,$source['ISEMERGENCYCALL']
                                                 ,$source['NOTABLECALLID']
                                                 ,$source['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID']
                                                 ,$source['ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO']
                                                 ,$source['ACCOUNTCODE']
                                                 ,$source['ACCOUNTCLIENT']
                                                 ,$source['ORIGINATINGLEGID']
                                                 ,$source['SYSTEMRESTARTNO']
                                                 ,$source['PATTERN']
                                                 ,$source['HOLDCOUNT']
                                                 ,$source['AUXSESSIONTYPE']
                                                 ,$source['DEVICEID1']
                                                 ,$source['DEVICEID2']
                                                 ,$source['ISLEG1ORIGINATING']
                                                 ,$source['ISLEG2ORIGINATING']
                                                 ,$source['GLOBALCALLID']
                                                 ,$source['CADTEMPLATEID']
                                                 ,$source['CADTEMPLATEID2']
                                                 ,$source['ts']
                                                 ,$source['INITIATOR']
                                                 ,$source['ACCOUNTNAME']
                                                 ,$source['APPNAME']
                                                 ,$source['CALLID']
                                                 ,$source['CHRTYPE']
                                                 ,$source['CALLERNAME']
                                                 ,$source['serviceid1']
                                                 ,$source['serviceid2']);

                                              $stmt->execute();
                          }
              }

     ?>
```

Comment: That's now how you bind.  It's $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$var,$var2,$var3,$var4). s for strings, i for integers.  Also your error is stating the number of binds you have don't match your ? placeholders

Comment: @Tom N. Don't add the SESSIONID in the insert you need only 58 column AI do the job for you ..

Comment: Oh no wonder! The person who assisted me with this gave me that format so I had no idea but now that makes more sense. So make sure they match obviously, and put all 59 variables in one set of parenthesis, got it! Thank you

Comment: @clearshot66 So after my 59 'sssisisisi' etc., I'll have ```$source['SESSIONTYPE']``` etc. as each variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is on **AI auto-increment** you dont need to add your **PRIMARY KEY COLUMN** in your **INSERT STATEMENT**

```
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO ambition.session (SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE,ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING,CREATIONTIMESTAMP,ALERTINGTIMESTAMP,CONNECTTIMESTAMP,DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP,HOLDTIMESECS,LEGTYPE1,LEGTYPE2,INTERNALPARTYTYPE1,INTERNALPARTYTYPE2,SERVICETYPEID1,SERVICETYPEID2,EXTENSIONID1,EXTENSIONID2,LOCATION1,LOCATION2,TRUNKGROUPNAME1,TRUNKGROUPNAME2,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO,ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1,SERVICEEXTENSION1,SERVICEEXTENSION2,SERVICENAME1,SERVICENAME2,MISSEDUSERID2,ISEMERGENCYCALL,NOTABLECALLID,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID,ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,ACCOUNTCODE,ACCOUNTCLIENT,ORIGINATINGLEGID,SYSTEMRESTARTNO,PATTERN,HOLDCOUNT,AUXSESSIONTYPE,DEVICEID1,DEVICEID2,ISLEG1ORIGINATING,ISLEG2ORIGINATING,GLOBALCALLID,CADTEMPLATEID,CADTEMPLATEID2,ts,INITIATOR,ACCOUNTNAME,APPNAME,CALLID,CHRTYPE,CALLERNAME,serviceid1,serviceid2)


                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") or die(mysqli_error($conn2)) ;
```

need the change your bin_param

```
//example here i guess **SESSIONTYPE COLUMN IS INTEGER**
$sth->bindParam(':SESSIONTYPE', $source['SESSIONTYPE'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but it still won't work. So I'll need to bind like clearshot said above, but remove instances of my primary key like you said

Comment: @Tom N. Yes you need to adapt in the context i guess ;).

Comment: That makes since, I didn't think about removing AI though, thank you

Comment: I've edited my code above: I took your advice and followed clearshot's format. All of my binds, values and variables match 58, they all have 58 elements but my error is still that number of elements int ype definition string don't match number of bind variables.

Comment: @TomN. the error mean you are a error on setting a column or more wich are type varchar or blob for string in general you got problem on setting your bin_params the http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php The characters in the string should not be separated by commas:

Comment: That fixed it, the commas were the issue! Thanks again. It's running now, no errors, but there are about 8000 new records so it may be a while before I see if it was successful or not